# Response body always null in android from retrofit2 api request

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm developing an android app with android studio, and I have a rest api, which I developed with spring. And every time I use retrofit to retrieve something from the server I get null body. Even though my server sends the data.

I've tried ScalarsConverterFactory and GsonConverterFactory, I tried as well changing the type of my Call to String, to ResponseBody and to JsonObject

here I make the call:

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("my_url")
                .build();

ServerService service = retrofit.create(ServerService.class);
Call<List<String>> call = service.getUserAlbums("addcookie");
Response<List<String>> response = call.execute();
```

ServerService.java

```java
@GET("/cmu/getUserAlbums")
Call<List<String>> getUserAlbums(@Header("Cookie") String cookie);
```

Here is the code in the server

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserAlbums", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public List<String> getUserAlbums() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(auth.getName());
        return userService.getUserByUsername(user.getUsername()).getAlbums();

    }
```

I was expecting to get a list as a string, I get the HTTP code 302, and in my console I can see that the server returns the List, but I can't receive on android.

Comment: strange, 302 is a redirect. Do you happen to know where it's redirecting to?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue, basically retrofit considers a response successful if the code is between 200 - 299, so as it was returning the 302, the response body I was looking for was in .errorBody().

Comment: can you plese confirm .response.errorBody().string()?

Answer (score 0):

Your error happens because you are returning Status Code `302 FOUND` in the controller. When retrieving data you should return `200 OK`.